# How to adapt my web page to different browser and different resolution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using asp.net MVC3 to create a website,but the webpage can not adapt to different browsers and resolution though i use the % in my webpage,anybody can help me?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why it might not be working but it's hard to say without more information. Make sure that your page validates. Sometimes invalid markup with simple solutions will cause perplexing rendering issues between browsers: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: You might have a look at "Responsive Web Desgin" (=> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design), which allows you to create different stylesheets certain resolutions/devices.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is not displaying properly.

I use the css grids and fonts from the [Yahoo User Interface](http://yuilibrary.com/) APIs.  This takes care of the basic browser differences for me.  Then I just add my HTML and CSS.  Go and download the framework, it is really good.  It will help you get a solid base for your CSS from which you can build.

All the best.